# Excel VBA comboboxes only populates when I run my sub twice

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have 8 comboboxes on a form that I wish to populate with saved values when the user opts to do so.

The problem I have is that although the code all works only the first combobox actually updates - unless I call the sub twice (i.e the user simply clicks the command button again) and then all comboboxes populate perfectly.

It's not complex code (at all) but clearly there is something I'm missing - I'm not sure why the comboboxes all update the second time the sub is run but not the first. Any ideas?

```
Dim loadlimit
Dim loadrow
Dim loadprev As Boolean
Dim l(8) As String
Dim i

i = 1

loadrow = 1
loadprev = False
loadlimit = lastrow(Sheet19)


Do Until loadrow > loadlimit
    If Cells(loadrow, 1).Value = geogselect.selectedind.Value Then
        loadprev = True
        l(1) = Cells(loadrow, 2).Value
        l(2) = Cells(loadrow, 3).Value
        l(3) = Cells(loadrow, 4).Value
        l(4) = Cells(loadrow, 5).Value
        l(5) = Cells(loadrow, 6).Value
        l(6) = Cells(loadrow, 7).Value
        l(7) = Cells(loadrow, 8).Value
        l(8) = Cells(loadrow, 9).Value
        geogselect.ComboBox1.Text = l(1)
        geogselect.ComboBox2.Text = l(2)
        geogselect.ComboBox3.Text = l(3)
        geogselect.ComboBox4.Text = l(4)
        geogselect.ComboBox5.Text = l(5)
        geogselect.ComboBox6.Text = l(6)
        geogselect.ComboBox7.Text = l(7)
        geogselect.ComboBox8.Text = l(8)
    End If
    loadrow = loadrow + 1
Loop
```

Thanks in hope!

Comment: Could you please post the code where geogselect is defined?

Comment: geogselect is the form, selectedind is a textbox where the controlsource is set to a specific cell. This cell is filled with a text string in another sub.

Comment: Then perhaps you should include this another sub. What you claim cannot be explained by looking at this code: it works (populate comboboxes) on account of the values in Cells(loadrow, 1).Value and geogselect.selectedind.Value. These variables are not being populated here and thus nothing can be said. Look at the place where these variables are being populated or include the corresponding code.

Comment: hmmm... thanks anyway...I see what you're saying but these are simply worksheet cells with text strings in so I had assumed (naively?) that as I know that these cells have a string in when this sub refers to them then the behaivour must be related to some elementary mistake or oversight I've made when setting the text property of the combobox.

Comment: I know that these are cells. But you can change their contents at runtime. Are you saying that your code does not change at all the values from Cells(loadrow, 1).Value or geogselect.selectedind.Value? Then what you say does not make any sense. The loop is pretty simple and the only way to affect its behaviour is through this condition; the fact of clicking once or twice does not change at all the values in this condition unless your code does it. If you don't know how to debug your code, you might upload the whole spreadsheet and I can take a quick look at it if you wish.

Comment: OK, I've had another look. The array populates with the right values every time. If I set a break on every line that updates a combobox, it works fine and I see all the values immediately every time. If I run the code with no breaks I still only see the value in the first combobox, until I re-run the code (making no changes) and I see all the values. Screenupdating is set to true at the end of the full sequence of subs. So it looks to me as if the issue is that Excel isn't displaying the values in the comboboxes, rather than with the code. Still don't know why, though! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Pretty weird. From your code, I cannot tell. I would need to look at the whole spreadsheet to get a better feeling of what might be happening.

Comment: Try refreshing each combo box after the last insert of items

Comment: Thanks MikeD. You put me in the right direction. SetFocus seems to have sorted it. I thought it would be something simple. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the assistance, telling Excel to setFocus before updating each combobox resolved this.